# .htaccess friendly url´s issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am implementing friendly URLs on my website.

At the moment I have some rules working but still need help to implement the last ones.

Rules working:

```
RewriteRule ^SobreNos$ /about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^Contactos$ /contact.php [L]
```

Rule Working but not as I wanted:

```
RewriteRule ^catalogo-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ catalogo.php?cat=$1
```

Rule not working:

```
RewriteRule 
^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1&ref=$2&cat=$3 [L]
```

About the 3rd rule, I wanted the friendly URL catalogo/homem and tried to change the - for the / but didn't work.

The 4th rule don´t work at all, with - or the /.

Could be a problem of the server's version? This is the version of the server "Apache ver.2.2.19 (Unix)".

My .htaccess file

```
RewriteBase /
Options -Indexes 
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^SobreNos$ /about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^Contactos$ /contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^catalogo-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ catalogo.php?cat=$1
RewriteRule   
 ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    product.php?id=$1&ref=$2&cat=$3    [NC,L]
```

Comment: What didn't work? Did you get 404 errors for the 3rd and 4th rules? Would you mind sharing the entire content of your `.htaccess` file (put it in your question)?

Comment: The 3rd rule is working. But not as i wanted. Working URL - www.example.com/catalogo-homem . But what i want is www.example.com/catalogo/homem...The 4rd rule gives me a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I have reformatted your file to the following:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^SobreNos$ about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^Contactos$ contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^catalogo/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ catalogo.php?cat=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^products/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1&ref=$2&cat=$3 [NC,L]
```

Here's what I've changed:

1. Moved your `RewriteBase` down below `RewriteEngin on`
2. Removed the leading slashes in the destinations for each rule (they are not needed because `RewriteBase` is set)
3. Removed `A-Z` from your expressions (because the `NC`, no case, flag is set)
4. Used the slash in the 3rd and 4th rules, and appended an optional ending slash.

My test show that everything works properly. The only reason a 404 would be thrown is if the file you are rewriting to (*product.php* for example) does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution for the problem.

```
Options -Indexes 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ catalogo.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/]+)$ catalogo.php?cat=$1&scat=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ product.php?cat=$1&scat=$2&name=$3&id=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Still have to add a rewrite rule for about.php and contactos.php, but not a huge problem.